# Extracting common lines from two text files using Python

Tags: python, json

A system outputs two variables of type string ; op1 as follows,

```
{"fname":"John","mname":"Smith","ID":"2711"}
{"fname":"Nick","mname":"Bart","ID":"3011"}
{"fname":"Nash","mname":"willy","ID":"2811"}
{"fname":"Jack","mname":"Tuna","ID":"2911"}
{"fname":"Peter","mname":"Jill","ID":"2611"}
{"fname":"Aaron","mname":"Sane","ID":"3111"}
```

and op2 as follows,

```
{"fname":"John","mname":"Smith","Age":"Berkley"}
{"fname":"Nash","mname":"willy","Age":"Godson"}
{"fname":"Jack","mname":"Tuna","Age":"Welch"}
```

I copy these values into 2 text files op1.txt and op2.txt ; I want to create a third variable (text file) which contains the IDs of only those whose first and last names are present in op2. Note that only 2 tags are common i.e `fname` and `lname`.

The output based on the above inputs must be **[2711, 2811, 2911]**

Is there a way to avoid writing it to a file and comparing at variable level itself ?

Comment: Just don't save it to a file and do the comparing "at variable level itself"

Comment: You should show what you wrote so far... if you can save the 'system outputs' into lists of dicts then you don't need files.

Comment: yes i was trying out the dict manipulations which didn't work (for a silly error). i could finally loop through both the files and convert to str to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 2 loops with 2 lists :

```
a = [
        {"fname":"John","lname":"Smith","ID":"2711"},
        {"fname":"Nick","lname":"Bart","ID":"3011"},
        {"fname":"Nash","lname":"willy","ID":"2811"},
        {"fname":"Jack","lname":"Tuna","ID":"2911"},
        {"fname":"Peter","lname":"Jill","ID":"2611"},
        {"fname":"Aaron","lname":"Sane","ID":"3111"}
    ]
b = [
    {"fname":"John","lname":"Smith","Age":"Berkley"},
    {"fname":"Nash","lname":"willy","Age":"Godson"},
    {"fname":"Jack","lname":"Tuna","Age":"Welch"},
    {"fname":"FakeJill","lname":"FakeJill","Age":"FakeJill"},
    {"fname":"FakeJack","lname":"FakeJack","Age":"FakeJack"}
     ]
c = []
```

and here you loop lists of dicts:

```
for itema in a:
    for itemb in b:
       if itema['fname'] == itemb['fname'] and itema['lname'] == itemb['lname'] :
           c.append(int(itema['ID']))
print(c)
```

The result will be this:
[2711, 2811, 2911]

Comment: noted, but since these are lines in a file so we need to convert them to a string to compare infact i was struggling with the same.

Comment: To use the above approach, only thing that need to be changed is `json.loads(itema)['fname']` to do the comparison

Comment: @nevosial if you said that you want "The output based on the above inputs must be [2711, 2811, 2911]"

if you want result  ["2711", "2811", "2911"] you should dont use ```int()```